# Setting the (already) active tab to perform function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to have the active tab serve as a button to close the content.

So Users can open and switch between the different tabs. However, if the User clicks the current active tab, then it will perform a function.

jQuery

```
$( "#outerWrapper" ).tabs();
$('#tabs .ui-tabs-active').on('click', function(){
        $(" #contentSection ").toggleClass("dn");
});
```

CSS

```
.dn{display:none}
```

HTML

```
<div id="outerWrapper" class="mainWrapper" >
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tab-1">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-2">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-3">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="contentSection">
            <div id="tab-1">AAA</div>
            <div id="tab-2">BBB</div>
            <div id="tab-3">CCC</div>
        </div>  
</div>
```

My best effort is this;
http://jsfiddle.net/noyhadar/np8p2oy0/31/

Which only recognized the first tab, as the mechanism I need.

Noy Hadar

Comment: The class keeps changing, so you'll need a delegated event handler, like this -> `$('#tabs').on('click', '.ui-tabs-active', function(){`, but that will toggle the class in weird patterns when clicking multiple tabs, so it's probably not at all the way to do this

Comment: Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/np8p2oy0/34/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the classes keeps changing, so you'll need a delegated event handler, but jQuery UI changes the classes before your event handler fires, so it won't work, it will always toggle the content.

You have to keep your own classes, and keep track of those, and not rely on jQuery UI at all, other than setting the default class at pageload

```
$( "#outerWrapper" ).tabs();

var li = $('#tabs li');

li.filter('.ui-tabs-active').addClass('my_active')

li.on('click', function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('my_active') ) {
        $(" #contentSection ").toggleClass("dn");
    } else {
        $(" #contentSection ").removeClass("dn");
        li.removeClass('my_active');
        $(this).addClass('my_active');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/np8p2oy0/35/)

Answer (score 1):

This code uses a delegated event handler like @adeneo recommended.

It uses a variable to hold the last opened tab.  It toggles the display if the tab *hasn't* changed, and it shows the content if the tab *has* changed.  There's no need for the `dn` class using this method:

```
$("#outerWrapper").tabs();

var lastTab = $('#tabs .ui-tabs-active')[0];

$('#tabs').on('click', '.ui-tabs-active', function(){
  if(this===lastTab) {
    $("#contentSection").toggle();
  }
  else {
    $("#contentSection").show();
  }
  lastTab= this;
});
```

### Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

**Original Answer**

Might have to delegate to `mousedown` vs `click` to avoid overlapping with the click handlers jquery ui already has in place.

http://jsfiddle.net/xLsuru1c/1/

```
$( "#outerWrapper" ).tabs();
$('#tabs').on('mousedown',  '.ui-state-active', function(){
    $(" #contentSection ").toggleClass("dn");
});
```

**EDIT:**

If those are the requirements, might be best to switch the event to `mouseup` to closer mirror the timing of `click`. Also, add a conditional:

http://jsfiddle.net/xLsuru1c/2/

```
$( "#outerWrapper" ).tabs();
$('#tabs').on('mouseup',  'li', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("ui-state-active")){
        $(" #contentSection ").toggleClass("dn");
    } else {
        $(" #contentSection ").removeClass("dn");
    }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work properly for all cases .. i know, I was playing with it and came to same conclusion as adeneo

Comment: Close, but I would need any other tab to reopen the content.